# Likert Scale Type Dependent variable and linear model

Tags: r, regression, likert

I’m a beginner to using R and have a project due in a couple of weeks I’ve been working on, basically choose any dataset and perform analysis on it. However you can only use a linear regression model not any others.

I chose my topic on leadership approval and how much they are liked.
So my dependent variable is on a scale of 0-10 with 0 being severely disliked and 10 like a lot..
So my plan was to have a few independent variables such as education, age, gender, then several national policies which are all in the dataset and see how much impact they all have

My concern is that as I’m about to start to get to the regression stage (done all the visualisations and statistics) that my whole things is invalid because it is not a continuous variable and only continuous variables can utilise the linear model. However the example I saw in the textbook was similar to mine except it was between 0-100. I have seen many people on the internet argue it is fine as there is 11 options to choose from even if it is a likert scale
Any thoughts would be appreciated as I am freaking out and can’t bear the thought of starting again with it due in two weeks

Comment: I personally use linear regression when the dependent variable is likert scale, but that doesn't mean I'm correct :) You should get more authoritative answers that explain *why* it is OK and under what circumstances, and whether it fits your case.

Comment: This paper shows how to fit an ordinal regression model using the brms package: https://journals.sagepub.com/doi/pdf/10.1177/2515245918823199